# Undefined reference to ros::init

Tags: ros, add-dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
When I am trying to catkin_make, I am getting this error:

```
CMakeFiles/parser.dir/src/parser.cpp.o: In function `main':
parser.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
parser.cpp:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&)'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x1ac): undefined reference to `ros::spin()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x22d): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x28f): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x2c6): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x2da): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
```

I am not sure why the error is coming from.
My executable file name is `parser.cpp`

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(gmm)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES gmm
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS other_catkin_pkg
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

#############
## Testing ##
#############

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(parser src/parser.cpp)
target_link_libraries(parser ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

This is my `package.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>gmm</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The gmm package</description>


  <maintainer email="joy@todo.todo">joy</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>


  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

   <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
   <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
   <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>  


   <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
   <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
   <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>  
  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

Could you please help me out here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249802/undefined-reference-to-ros::init/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2016-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are declaring in your package manifest that your project depends on std_msgs, sensor_msgs and roscpp but you forgot to tell cmake about it.

In your CMakeLists.txt file replace the line:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
```

for:

```
find_package(catking REQUIRED COMPONENTS std_msgs sensor_msgs roscpp)
```

That way catkin can find the appropriate headers and libraries for your project.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-11**:
@Joy16: perhaps [CMakeLists.txt vs package.xml](http://answers.ros.org/question/217475) can shed some light on why you have to 'duplicate' this information in both.

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2016-12-11**:
Thanks! That worked.